# How to understand the Java tutorial internationalisation Customizing Resource Bundle Loading example?

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

I saw this code from an Oracle Java tutorial and I'm confused as to how it actually works. I am seeking the answers to several questions:

1) I don't see `public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale)` been called from anywhere, so how does it actually gets executed?

2) what is passed as arguments to `public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale)`

3) `public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale)` returns a `List<Locale>`, what's the purpose of returning a `List<Locale>`

4) `public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale)` return `super.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale);` if none of the `if` statement is satisfied, which is the class the keyword super referring to?

```
public class RBControl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(Locale.CHINA);
    test(new Locale("zh", "HK"));
    test(Locale.TAIWAN);
    test(Locale.CANADA);
    }

    private static void test(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Internationalisation/RBControl", locale,
         new ResourceBundle.Control() {
         @Override
         public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale) {
             if (baseName == null)
             throw new NullPointerException();
             if (locale.equals(new Locale("zh", "HK"))) {
             return Arrays.asList(
                 locale,
                 Locale.TAIWAN,
                 // no Locale.CHINESE here
                 Locale.ROOT);
             } else if (locale.equals(Locale.TAIWAN)) {
             return Arrays.asList(
                 locale,
                 // no Locale.CHINESE here
                 Locale.ROOT);
             }
             return super.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale);
         }
         });
    System.out.println("locale: " + locale);
    System.out.println("\tregion: " + rb.getString("region"));
    System.out.println("\tlanguage: " + rb.getString("language"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it may be quite hard to answer your questions, as your code style predates Java 7 (are you an archaeologist?), but I will try.

1. I can only assure you that `getCandidateLocales(String, String)` is actually called when the code is searching for the valid file name or class name to load textual resources from. For example:

   ```
   // ResourceBundle.java line 1314
   private static ResourceBundle getBundleImpl(String baseName, Locale locale,
                                               ClassLoader loader, Control control) {
       // (...) many lines removed
       // line 1352 - loop through files to find the best one
       ResourceBundle baseBundle = null;
       for (Locale targetLocale = locale;
            targetLocale != null;
            targetLocale = control.getFallbackLocale(baseName, targetLocale)) {
           // line 1356, there you are
           List<Locale> candidateLocales = control.getCandidateLocales(baseName, targetLocale);
           if (!isKnownControl && !checkList(candidateLocales)) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Control: getCandidateLocales");
           }

           bundle = findBundle(cacheKey, candidateLocales, formats, 0, control, baseBundle);

           // lengthy comment removed for clarity
           if (isValidBundle(bundle)) {
              // checking if it is the right one, removed
           }
       }

       // logic to deal with missing file, removed    
       return bundle;
   }
   ```
2. I believe it now should be obvious, but let me go into details. Suppose you have your messages in form of properties files: `messages.properties` - base, default language resources, `messages_fr.properties` - base French resources, `messages_fr_CA.properties` - French Canadian resources and finally `messages_de.proprties` - base German resources. The base name is as you might guess base file name, `messages` that is. Candidate locale is the User Interface locale.
   If you're working on a desktop application (highly unlikely) or a mobile application then UI Locale could be obtained by simply calling `Locale.getDetault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY)`. In older versions of Java it would be just `Locale.getDefault()`. In a web application, the solution actually depends on both the technology (i.e. Spring, JSF, Thymeleaf, Play, ...) and your approach to locale detection. Anyway, you should first try the most specialized one, than fall back. For instance, the French Canadian user (language tag fr-CA) should have seen contents of `messages_fr_CA.properties`, whereas other users of French language should be served with contents of `messages_fr.properties`. Likewise any other locale, should observe the translations taken from `messages.properties`.
   What this method does is, it will generate the fallback locales for a user (i.e. for input `Locale.forLanguageTag("fr-CA")` it will return the input itself, French Locale ("fr"), and an undefined locale marker ("und"). The last one tells the `ResourceBundle` to use the default file.
3. It returns the list of fallback locales, as I explained above.
4. It calls the method in a parent class - `ResourceBundle.Control`. The anonymous inner class defined in the code listing you attached actually derives from [ResourceBundle.Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! it is more than I had ever hoped for! btw, I was intrigued by your comment that this code style predates java7. I didn't come up with the code myself, I actually found it at Java tutorial Oracle. So does it mean that the Oracle Tutorials are out of date?

Comment: @Tony: Well, unfortunately it takes time to keep things up to date, so I guess the answer is to some extent yes. The code still works, but there are things that needs refreshing, i.e. `Objects.requireNonNull(basename);` instead of manual null check and `Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-HK")` instead of directly calling a constructor. The latter might be controversial though.